# Red5 on local PC

Tags: video-streaming, red5

I want to use my PC for Red5 server. PC work under Windows7. Modem huawei smartax mt880(Router mode) + external router(because I no one in LAN).
I opened for redirect on my local IP next UDP +TCP ports: 1935,5080,8088 via NAT tab in modem settings. FareWall is down. Red5 was installed with next settings: IP=192.168.1.2 (this is my IP in LAN) and port=5080. If I write in address browser 192.168.1.2 then Red5 page settings will be open. But if try open my external static IP, then no result.
How I can share my PC with local Red5 for other Internet users?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an address in the private range you have to map that address to your external IP. This is normally done using your router and since I dont have experience with that modem I cant comment on its settings. If your router / modem has a DMZ you could try directing it to your PC's IP 192.168.1.2. This is exactly what I do during testing on my windows 7 pc, but I use a linksys router.